# Find sets of 3 or more documents that share the same 'date' value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to return 'blocked-days' from an API, which mean dates that are repeated at least 3 times in the 'shippingDate' values of 'orders' collection documents.

Example:

```
{
shippingDate: 'sunday'
},
{
shippingDate: 'monday'
},
{
shippingDate: 'sunday'
},
{
shippingDate: 'tuesday'
},
{
shippingDate: 'sunday'
},
{
shippingDate: 'wednesday'
}
```

Will return `['sunday']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregation like this:

- `$group` by the days, adding one using `$sum` to get for each day how many times appears.
- `$match` where a day appears at least three times
- `$project` to return only the name of the day.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$shippingDate",
      "days": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "days": {
        "$gte": 3
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "days": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Which returns

```
[
  {
    "_id": "sunday"
  }
]
```

MongoDB uses JSON format so you retrieve JSON format. Using mongoose you can try this:

```js
const queryResult = [
  {
    "_id": "sunday"
  }
]

const desiredValue = queryResult.map(m => m._id)

console.log(desiredValue)
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/29wGWu9Vg40)